# Running Batch File when Windows Vmware boots up

Tags: batch-file, vmware

I need to run a batch file whenever my Windows 10 VMware boots up ..i have tried the scheduler and put the exe path in the start up folder but it appears that works only when the user logs into the Vmware and not when the Vmware is booting up. 
has any of you already solved this ?? if yes, how ?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/38ce8ce8-d27e-4d67-89da-24735ea629ce/task-scheduler-trigger-at-system-startup-what-does-it-actually-mean?forum=winservergen Is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler comes with an option called "System Startup". This means when *both Windows **and** Task Scheduler* successfully started up.

---

[image: The "When the computer starts" means "System Startup"]

You should select `When the computer starts` for trigger. And `run a program` for action. Fill in the path to your script and arguments if necessary.